# WebService - Envio de objetos via HttpGet

Tags: c#

Estou desenvolvendo um serviço `Get` de dados com retorno em *JSON*, seguindo o modelo abaixo:

**Pesquisar Questionário:**

```
{
[SchSISQST].[Qst]. QstAltDat
[SchSISQST].[Qst]. QstNom
[SchSISQST].[Qst]. QstAtvSit
[SchSISQST].[QstGrp]. QstGrpNom
[SchSISQST].[QstSbo]. QstSboNom
}
```

Eu já tenho seguintes estruturas do meu *Entity Framework Core*:

Classes:

**Questionario.cs**

```
 public partial class Questionario
{
    public short QstCod { get; set; }
    public string QstNom { get; set; }
    public bool QstAtvSit { get; set; }
    public decimal QstCpfAltNum { get; set; }
    public DateTime QstAltDat { get; set; }
}
```

**GrupoQuestionario.cs**

```
public partial class GrupoQuestionario
{
    public short QstGrpCod { get; set; }
    public string QstGrpNom { get; set; }
    public decimal QstGrpCpfAltNum { get; set; }
    public DateTime QstGrpAltDat { get; set; }
}
```

**SubGrupoQuestionario.cs**

```
public partial class SubGrupoQuestionario
{
    public short QstSboCod { get; set; }
    public short QstGrpCod { get; set; }
    public string QstSboNom { get; set; }
    public decimal QstSboCpfAltNum { get; set; }
    public DateTime QstSboAltDat { get; set; }
}
```

**QuestionarioSubGrupo.cs**

```
 public partial class QuestionarioSubGrupo
{
    public short QstCod { get; set; }
    public short QstSboCod { get; set; }
    public short QstGrpCod { get; set; }
}
```

**ListarQuestionariosRepository.cs**

```
public class ListarQuestionariosRepository
{
    public void ListarQuestionario()
    {
        using(SisquestDataContext Db = new SisquestDataContext())
        {
            //return Db.Set<Questionario>().ToList();

            var finalQuest = (from qst in Db.Questionario
                    join qstSubGrp in Db.QuestionarioSubGrupo on qst.QstCod equals qstSubGrp.QstCod
                    join qstGrup in Db.GrupoQuestionario on qstSubGrp.QstGrpCod equals qstGrup.QstGrpCod
                    join qstSubGrpQuest in Db.SubGrupoQuestionario on qstSubGrp.QstSboCod equals qstSubGrpQuest.QstSboCod
                    select new { qst.QstAltDat, qst.QstNom, qst.QstAtvSit, qstGrup.QstGrpNom, qstSubGrpQuest.QstSboNom }).ToList();

        }
    }

}
```

Equivalente a minha *query* que traz os 5 campos que preciso capturar em formato *JSON*, seguindo abaixo:

```
   SELECT a.QstAltDat, a.QstNom, a.QstAtvSit, c.QstGrpNom, d.QstSboNom FROM SchSISQST.Qst a INNER JOIN SchSISQST.QstSboAsa b ON b.QstCod = a.QstCod INNER JOIN SchSISQST.QstGrp c ON c.QstGrpCod = b.QstGrpCod INNER JOIN SchSISQST.QstSbo d ON d.QstSboCod = b.QstSboCod
```

**IListarQuestionariosRepository.cs**

```
public interface IListarQuestionariosRepository
{
    IEnumerable<Questionario> ListarQuestionario { get; }
    //IEnumerable<GrupoQuestionario> GrupoQuestionario { get; }
    //IEnumerable<QuestionarioSubGrupo> QuestionarioSubGrupo { get; }
}
```

**ListarQuestionariosModel.cs**

```
[Serializable]
public class ListarQuestionariosModel
{
    public DateTime QstAltDat { get; set; }
    public string QstNom { get; set; }
    public bool QstAtvSit { get; set; }
    public string QstGrpNom { get; set; }
    public string QstSboNom { get; set; }
}
```

**SisquestController.cs**

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ListarQuestionarios()
    {
        //return _contextSisquest.Questionario.ToList();
        ListarQuestionariosModel listarQuestionariosModel = new ListarQuestionariosModel();
        try
        {


            //var listarQuestionariosRepository = new ListarQuestionariosRepository();
            //listarQuestionariosRepository.ListarQuestionario();
            foreach (var item in collection)
            {

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest(ex);
        }
    }
```

Estou tento um erro no `ActionResult ListarQuestionarios` chamado '*not all code paths return value*' e gostaria de tentar entender isso, outro ponto é chamar os 5 membros como retorno no meu foreach seguindo o `ListarQuestionariosModel` que criei, pois tenho aqui uma questão de pegar dois campos de outras tabelas, isso eu ainda não tinha feito que são `QstGrpNom` e `QstSboNom`, quando é de apenas 1 tabela eu consigo montar o serviço get, existe alguma maneira utilizando as boas práticas de conseguir retornar os campos baseado no *LINQ* que montei e demais partes das regras? Obrigado pessoal.

Comment: Leandro, sua questão está muito vaga. O erro que colocou no final ele mesmo diz que sua action não retorna valor. Sua controller está muito incompleta, parece que você mesmo não sabe muito bem oque fazer ali e nem uma View dela apresentou com oque/como pretende exibir. Tente melhorar a questão e deixa-la mais objetiva, será mais fácil achar ajuda.

Comment: Ok, obrigado. Vou analisar de forma melhor e retorno George Wurthmann